# Parse JSON response of twitter search api with c#

Tags: c#, json, twitter

I can't understand what I do wrong parsing JSon response from twitter search API. In debug mode in Visual Studio I see the tweets in JSON format, but I can't get the values of them. 
This is my code:

```
var requestUserTimeline = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23moscow"));
requestUserTimeline.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage responseUserTimeLine = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestUserTimeline);

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(await responseUserTimeLine.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
foreach(var item in json)
{
      Console.WriteLine(item.statuses.text);
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: That's not how it works. To dynamically deserialize JSON, use `JToken`, `JObject` and stuff...

Comment: are you sure you need to parse json manually? there are lot of libraries that takes care of all these things e.g Tweetinvi,

Comment: @deeiip To tell the truth now I need any way that works... Because I am tired to look for solution. Thatnk you for Tweetinvi

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ  Thank you - I will search for JToken and JObject

Comment: did you find its solution?